# .Net Core 8 Identity Web API with External(Google, Facebook) Logins

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-8

I'm encountering challenges while implementing .NET Core Identity 8 in my Web API project. I've followed the official documentation, but I'm facing issues with Google Login. I don't know what's the problem. It might be a cookie issue or something else.

1. Installed the necessary NuGet packages for Identity 8.
2. Configured the Identity services in Program.cs.
3. Set up my DbContext and models.
4. Implemented Google Authentication.

I've checked my configurations and followed the documentation closely, but I'm unable to figure out what might be causing this issue. Could someone provide insights or point me in the right direction to resolve this?

Here are snippets of my code for reference:

Program.cs file

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Core8IdentityWEBAPI.Controllers;
using Core8IdentityWEBAPI.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var services = builder.Services;
var configuration = builder.Configuration;
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
    });
    options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();

});
builder.Services.AddDbContext<Core8IdentityWEBAPI.Data.AppContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

// Add Session
//builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
//{
//    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);//We set Time here 
//    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
//    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
//});
// Add CORS
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});

builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Core8IdentityWEBAPI.Data.AppContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
{
    auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    auth.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/login";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
        options.LoginPath = "/login";
        options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);

        // Set SameSite mode to Lax
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
    })
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google:ClientId").Value;
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google:ClientSecret").Value;
    googleOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    //googleOptions.CallbackPath = "/api/Auth/GoogleResponse"; // Set the callback path
    googleOptions.CallbackPath = "/signin-google"; // Set the callback path

})
    .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
    {
        facebookOptions.AppId = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Facebook:AppId").Value;
        facebookOptions.AppSecret = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret").Value;
        facebookOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    });


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Your API V1");
        // Other configuration options...
    });
}
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.MapIdentityApi<IdentityUser>();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();


app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors(builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader();
});

//app.UseSession();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

var cookiePolicyOptions = new CookiePolicyOptions
{
    MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax,
    HttpOnly = Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.HttpOnlyPolicy.Always,
    Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
};

/*Use Cookie Policy*/
app.UseCookiePolicy(cookiePolicyOptions);


app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

AuthController Method

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleLogin([FromServices] IDistributedCache distributedCache)
{
    // Generate a unique state value
    //var state = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    //// Store the state value in the distributed cache
    //var cacheKey = $"GoogleAuthenticationState:{state}";
    //await distributedCache.SetStringAsync(cacheKey, "valid", new DistributedCacheEntryOptions
    //{
    //    AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10) // Set an expiration time
    //});

    await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("Google", new AuthenticationProperties() {
        //RedirectUri = Url.Action("GoogleResponse", "Auth", null, Request.Scheme),
        RedirectUri = "/signin-google"
    });
    //_logger.LogInformation($"Callback Sent. State: {state}");
    var googleAuthUrl = HttpContext.Response.Headers["Location"];

    // Return the URL as a response
    return Ok(new { GoogleAuthUrl = googleAuthUrl });

}
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "but I'm facing issues with Google Login" What's the problem do you meet ? Could you share the error messages ?